# Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1. "InfInt.h" toString function

Tags: c++

I am using c++ to solve a problem. I need to find the factorial of 100 and find the sum of its digits. Because of the limitation of the variables in c++ I am using a header file called infint (https://code.google.com/p/infint/). It has its own function to convert an InfInt to a string. However I am getting this error:"Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1." I am using xcode also.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "InfInt.h"
#define INFINT_USE_EXCEPTIONS
using namespace std;
int main() {
    InfInt result=1;
    for (int x=100;x>0;x--) {
        result*=x;
    }
    cout<<result<<endl;
    InfInt I;
    string sresult = I.toString(result);
    cout<<sresult<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot include the full header code but you can download it from the link.

Part of header for toString:

```
inline std::string InfInt::toString() const
{//PROFILED_SCOPE
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << *this;
    return oss.str();
}
```

There are other references to the method in the header file but I believe this is the only important part.

Comment: It's right there in the error message: you're passing an argument to a function that doesn't take any.

Comment: What part of the error message didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "InfInt.h"
#define INFINT_USE_EXCEPTIONS
using namespace std;
int main() {
    InfInt result=1;
    for (int x=100;x>0;x--) {
        result*=x;
    }
    cout<<result<<endl;
    string sresult = result.toString();
    cout<<sresult<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `result` is an `InfInt` object and that this object has a method `toString()` that returns a string representation of it.

Comment: Thank you, I just had a friend help me today and he told me the same thing. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: @skyclan9, if one of the answers provided to you here answers the question you asked, you should mark that answer as accepted. If an answer is helpful, you can upvote it. If no answer answers your question, you should try refining your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what the error message says. You are passing an argument to `toString` when you shouldn't:

```
string sresult = I.toString(result);
```

instead of

```
string sresult = result.toString();
```